How to extend MUI generic types when using forwardRef?
I'm trying to create a wrapper around the MenuItem component that modifies defaults and adds one new prop - testId.
If I simply do it this way:
export type MyMenuItemProps = MenuItemProps & { testId?: string }

I'll lose the generic type behavior of MenuItemProps, where some props depend on the type of the component prop.
I also need to use React.forwardRef to pass the ref prop to MenuItem rendered by MyMenuItem. Something like this:
const BaseMenuItem = forwardRef<HTMLLIElement, BaseMenuItemProps>(
  ({ testId, ...props }, ref) => (
    <MenuItem
      {...props}
      ref={ref}
      data-test-id={testId}
    />
  ),
)

but with generics.
I can probably do something like this:
export type BaseMenuItemProps<RootElement extends React.ElementType = 'li'> =
  MenuItemProps<RootElement, { testId?: string }>


but I'm not sure how to use it correctly with forwardRef, especially that the type here is element type (e.g. 'li' or 'a'), but forwardRef gets HTML element interface (e.g. HTMLLiElement) as the first parameter.
What's the best way to do it?
